# left join - infinite loop (never returns)

Tags: sql-server-2008, left-join, isnull

I have a table and one complex view with following row counts

table cpi - number of rows = 74559
view most_recent - number of rows = 69832

then i tried to do the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 201 cpi.cbuno,  cpi.casebook, v.status_uno
 FROM CPI cpi 
 inner JOIN most_recent v ON v.cbuno=cpi.cbuno
 where isnull(v.status_uno, -1) = 669
```

and i got results quickly. then i tried it with a left join as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 201 cpi.cbuno,  cpi.casebook, v.status_uno
 FROM CPI cpi 
 left JOIN most_recent v ON v.cbuno=cpi.cbuno
 where isnull(v.status_uno, -1) = 669
```

then its going through an infinite loop..never returns a value. and one more thing to mention if i use v.status_uno = 669 instead of (v.status_uno, -1) = 669 in where clause, it goes through the same infinite loop. Do you guys have any idea about this?

Appreciate your help

thanks,
keth

Comment: hello Olaf, yes its a typo, sorry for that..i just fixed it, thanx

Comment: how many nulls do you have in most_recent.cbuno and most_recent.status_uno?

Comment: there is no null in most_recent.cbuno, but there 25 rows with nulls for most_recent.status_uno

Comment: How many rows in recent?  It is more of a performance issue. I do not believe you can get an infinite loop in SQL. But you can have extremely non-performant queries

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 201 cpi.cbuno,  cpi.casebook, v.status_uno
 FROM CPI cpi 
 LEFT JOIN most_recent v 
   ON v.cbuno=cpi.cbuno 
     and v.status_uno=669
```

Comment: Hello xQbert, thanx for the reply. Yes i tried that but no luck

Comment: both tables have a column named cbuno and both tables have that column indexed or setup as a primary key/foreign key relationship right?   at this point we'd need to see results of a query analysis (what indexes it's using, if it's doing a table scan and where etc.

Comment: most_recent is view not a table, and CPI.cpi is the primary key for CPI table and it has a pk index

Comment: The view is likely the problem.  Unless it's an indexed view you can't put an index on it and it will not use indexes.  So the left join is having to do a full table scan for each of the records in the table. So it's having to join each row 69832 times. all without the benefit of an index.  Look at creating an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864(v=sql.105).aspx) instead of just a view and watch the performance soar.  from not having to generate the Cartesian of over 5 billion records. or [msft link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.105).aspx)